# How can I instantiate LocalReport with ReportViewerCore.NETCore package?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reporting, rdlc

**Problem:**

I try to instantiate LocalReport (*using var report = new LocalReport();*) *ReportViewerCore.NETCore* package and I get the following error message:

> System.MethodAccessException: 'Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore.LocalReport..ctor()' to access method 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.StandalonePreviewStore..ctor()' failed.'

**Objectif:**

Implement subreport in report.

Reporting works when I use *AspNetCore.Reporting* package, but I don't have any clue how to do with the *AspNetCore.Reporting* package. When I try implementing subreport, i get the following message:

> The subreport '*a_subreport*' could not be found at the specified location ... Please verify that the subreport has been published and that the name is correct.

**Tries:**

Finding//implementing solution with similar topic in stackoverflow, in CodeProject and related topics from diverse site / youtube videos.

Framework NET CORE 5.0

By the way, I am new with rdlc report.

Comment: Pls check [the blogs first](http://blog.geveo.com/IntegratingRDLCReportsToNetCoreProjects), if you still face the same issue, you can edit this post.

Comment: Microsoft never released AspNetCore.Reporting  or Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore packages. There's no `Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore` package in NuGet.  MS didn't even migrate the viewer to ASP.NET MVC. Which package are you actually using? Post the link to NuGet or the Github repo

Comment: The [AspNetCore.Reporting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Reporting) package was last updated in 2018, 4 years ago. Some of its dependencies are unlisted (ie removed from NuGet), others were replaced (System.Data.SqlClient was replaced by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) and the project's site is down.

Comment: Sorry about the naming of the package Microsoft.Reporting.NetCore, the one I meant to is the ReportviewerCore.NETcore (i'll rectify the name, i mention the name for the import : using Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore). The package which I used is: ReportViewerCore.NETCore from: https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore/